# Brick install on covered porch

Tags: brick, patio, gap

The stone covered exterior wall of my new custom home, approaches the entry way to the front door as attached columns under roof (that is, the exterior wall juts into the entryway about 12" under cover in what might be described as attached columns). Those stone columns then return back to the interior wall of the entry which is brick. I noticed that the brick inside the entry is installed against the Tyvek (all of the exterior brick has the requisite gap). I asked the very experienced mason about not having the gap on the inside and he said it was to allow room for the casing / frame around the front door and it would be okay because it is against Tyvek, has weep holes, is well shielded from the elements, (though a heavy wind could blow rain against the lower part). It has weep holes, the other side of the wall on one side is all exterior stone with gap and on the other side is part exterior and part interior. The area is about 7 x 8. Do I need to have him tear out those two walls and redo, and have a small door casing trim? Or will it be okay as he said? Initially, when we did our first planning walk, he noted that it would have the gap so I was surprised that it didn't. These are very experienced custom home masons.

Comment: Very experienced custom home masons should know what they are doing, more than Joe handyman down the road.  The masons's name about their work is what keeps them working.

Comment: I would ask the mason about it - ask why it was indicated that it _would_ have a gap during the initial walk through and why it doesn't now. Don't be confrontational about it, just inquisitive and wanting to learn. "I'm confused, I could have sworn that initially you said there would be a gap here, and now there isn't and you say it's OK. What's changed? Why is it OK now when it wasn't before?" If you ask really nicely, he may admit a mistake and redo it, or he may have a good reason based upon additional information.

Comment: Also, a picture or two are worth thousands of words trying to describe the situation. You can [edit] those into your question.